# Inserting std::set as keys to std::map

Tags: c++

I am using `std::set<std::uint32_t>` as keys to a `std::map`. I have read on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) that `std::set` implements the Compare operation via `std::lexicographical_compare` of two `std::set`- what does this actually mean?

Also, is it possible for two `std::set` with the same `std::uint32_t`s inserted, but in different order, to not evaluate equal?

Comment: Did you follow the link to [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) to see what it does?

Comment: Also, `std::set` is an ordered container.   Insertion order != stored order

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking in terms of an underlying binary search tree implementing the set, and different insertion order of the same elements producing different trees. Yet such trees have the same sort/lexicographic order, so the comparison is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says - comparing two sets does so *lexicographically*.

The very same site [tells you what that means](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) if you simply click through:

> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.

Simplified, it basically means an intuitive element-by-element comparison from left-to-right ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Numeral_systems_and_dates)).

As for your second question, the contents of a `set<int>` are in increasing numerical order, irrespective of what order you inserted the elements, so no.

Comment: I believe specifically cppreference is referring to the interaction with the `Compare` template parameter for `std::set` (default `std::less<Key>`). Likewise that makes your "are in increasing numerical order" the default, but you could make it store in say the opposite order.

Comment: @FireLancer Yes, you can override the comparator if you like.

Comment: @FireLancer The difference/effect of what? What is "it"? I don't know what you're asking, sorry. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: On what the OP linked, I assume they wrote that for some reason. "Compares the contents of lhs and rhs lexicographically. The comparison is performed by a function equivalent to `std::lexicographical_compare`. **This comparison ignores the container's ordering Compare.**"

Comment: @FireLancer Ah, interesting, so yeah the ordering is _always_ lexicographical and the `Compare` that maintains order within each container is just ignored. There's no "effect" of that other than what it says

Answer (score 1):

> I have read on cppreference that `std::set` implements the Compare operation via `std::lexicographical_compare` of two `std::set` - what does this actually mean?

It means that the comparison operator of `std::set` calls `std::lexicographical_compare` with the range of the elements of the operands as arguments, and returns the result. `std::lexicographical_compare` compares the lexicographical order of the operand ranges. This is the same order as is used to order words in a dictionary.

> Also, is it possible for two `std::set` with the same `std::uint32_t`s inserted, but in different order ...

`std::set` is ordered. All sets with same comparison function have the same order. Elements that compare less are before elements that compare as higher. Thus, if both elements and the comparison function are the same, then the sets will compare equal in lexicographical comparison.

If the comparison function is stateless, then all instances of it produce the same order. In theory, a stateful comparison function could produce a different order for different set. I would recommend to avoid such counter-intuitive comparison functions.